# Feature request - Bounty sharing

Tags: feature-request, bounty

Sometimes, I see a question that is worthy of a bounty. However, someone has already placed a bounty on it, so I have to wait about a week until it expires.

So, I'd like to request "bounty sharing" where two or more people can pool points together to share in a bounty reward. I think this would raise the reward while lessening some burden on one person.

Sometimes a larger reward becomes a greater incentive for people to respond to the question.

Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Who would choose the bounty reaper?

Comment: @msh210 Good question. If it's shared, I don't think it would matter. While this may add some complexity, perhaps, one person can start the bounty and if others want to pool, there could be an "invite" button or something similar where the original person can accept or reject the invite? At that point, it's agreed that anyone can choose the reaper. Perhaps we should assume that all involved might chat at some point, before some decision is made.

Comment: More time on the featured list is almost certainly more valuable in terms of attracting answers than a somewhat larger number of points. Just start a second bounty after if the first isn't effective